# Enviar o valor de um input via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Olá pessoal tenho um input com a seguente função

```
<input id="cpf"onblur="buscacpf()">
```

abaixo está a função .

```
<script>
function buscacpf() {
  var x = document.getElementById("cpf").value;

alert(x);
}
</script>
```

algo bem básico ou seja quando eu saiu desse input pelo metodo onblur ele me retorno o valor que foi digitado no input, porem preciso pegar esse valor que é um cpf e retorno o nome do cliente, algumas pesquisas feitas na internet me levaram a fazer isso via ajax, mas sou iniciante e não sei como fazer isso dar certo.

Como é o script do ajax que vai pegar esse valor e enviar para outra pagina, isso dando certo já seria 50% porque a consulta eu sei fazer ai só restaria retornar essa consulta para a primeira pagina .

Comment: Pesquise por "AJAX" no campo de pesquisa do site que existem inúmeros exemplos.

Comment: Já fiz isso mas aparece inúmeros assuntos bem mais avançados nada parecido com o meu, tem algum post  parecido com esse meu problema ?

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada [nesta doc da W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)... tem até um exemplo básico e funcional. Basicamente é: vc faz uma requisição a um arquivo no servidor (ex. PHP) enviando o número do CPF, pesquisa o CPF no banco de dados e retorna o nome.

Comment: Josenildo, o AJAX é realmente muito bom, existe muitas bibliotecas que auxiliam na criança de códigos Ajax, facilitando sua criação. Uma delas é a mais famosa e conhecida biblioteca javascript JQuery. [Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) tem um link que pode te ajudar a fazer sua solução.